# Why swap() function can't work with vector's iterator?

Tags: c++

I just can't undestand why swap() function can't work? It also receives two iterators. Can anyone tell me the reason?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    vector<int> vt;
    vt.push_back(0);
    vt.push_back(1);

    vector<int>::iterator it1 = vt.begin();
    vector<int>::iterator it2 = ++vt.begin();
    cout << vt[0];  // 0
    cout << vt[1] << endl; // 1

    swap(it1, it2);

    cout << vt[0]; // still 0
    cout << vt[1] << endl; // still 1

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Try printing `*it1` and `*it2` after the `swap`.

Comment: C++ iterators aren't C pointers.

Comment: "*[swap()] receives two iterators*" - no it doesn't. Look at it again more carefully. It receives two references to values, not iterators.

Answer (score 12):

`swap()` literally swaps what is passed to it.  In your case, it is swapping `it1` and `it2` themselves, not the content they "point" to.  You can use [`std::iter_swap()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/iter_swap) instead to swap the content that two iterators "point" to.

Answer (score 2):

`swap` swaps iterator not the content iterator points to. what you need is `iter_swap`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try it like this

The pointer values `*a` and `*b` use be `iterator` with `swap`.

`swap(*it1, *it2);`